# Kannada page numbers in xelatex

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, indic

I am not able to get page numbers in Kannada even after i set it as my main language.

```
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Kannada]{kannada}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide not just a code snippet but a [minimum working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix. For sure, you've got to indicate which font you use.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing applicable in the language definition file (`.ldf`) yet, but adapting code from other modules and changing to Kannada seems to work:

[image: sections and footnotes]

[image: footnotes and pagenumbers]

You must use a font that contains the digits.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\kannadafont{Noto Sans Kannada}[Script=Kannada]
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Kannada]{kannada}

\makeatletter
%---
\def\kannadadigits#1{\expandafter\@kannada@digits #1@}
\def\@kannada@digits#1{%
  \ifx @#1% terminate
  \else % ೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯
    \ifcase#1೦\or೧\or೨\or೩\or೪\or೫\or೬\or೭\or೮\or೯\fi
    \expandafter\@kannada@digits
  \fi
}
%---
\def\kannadanumber#1{%
      \kannadadigits{\number#1}%
}
%---
     \let\@arabic\kannadanumber%
%---
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{ಕನ್ನಡ}
ಕಖಗಘ
\subsection{ಕನ್ನಡ}
ಕಖಗಘ
\kannadanumber{132 456 987}

೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯
\section{ಕಖಗಘ}
\today
\subsection{ಕಖಗಘ}

\section{ಕಖಗಘ}
ಕಖಗಘ\footnote{ಕಖಗಘ} ಕಖಗಘ\footnote{ಕಖಗಘ} ಕಖಗಘ\footnote{ಕಖಗಘ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working. Can we add this to kannada.ldf ?

Comment: @karthikholla Yes. It will affect the whole document. Maybe also useful for other cases and users might be to add digit choice as a package/language option.

Comment: @karthikholla Look at `bengalidigits.sty` code and bengali.ldf - these have the program logic that can be used.